# How to scan data in java for automated testing

Tags: java, java-io, bufferedinputstream

I am submitting code on codechef for automated testing, How ever my program works perfectly by gapping data from files. I modified the main function for it to obtain data from console (stdin).
The input file is as such

3 5

2 5 2

3 2 4 2 2 2 1 4 1 1 1 1 0

My problem is when I paste the data on console the first and second lines are read automatically but the program waits for me to press enter before it reads the last line(longest line).

From views Java programmers have less luck with i/o on codechef! thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] strNums;
    try {
        // read first line
        strNums = in.readLine().split("\\s");

        int numStacks = Integer.parseInt(strNums[0]);
        System.out.println("Num Stacks:" + numStacks);
        int stackMax = Integer.parseInt(strNums[1]);
        System.out.println("Stack Max:" + stackMax);

        System.out.println("Intinial Configs:");
        // read second line
        strNums = in.readLine().split("\\s");

        int[] stackSizes = new int[numStacks];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStacks; i++) {
            stackSizes[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
            // System.out.print(stackSizes[i] + ", ");

        }

        StackVideoGame myGame = new StackVideoGame(numStacks, stackMax, stackSizes);

        // read third line (which waits for an enter command!)
        strNums = in.readLine().split("\\s");
        for (int i = 0; i < strNums.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]));
            myGame.play(Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]));
            System.out.println("");

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < myGame.stacks.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(myGame.stacks[j].size() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you didn´t just accidently copy the linebreaks for the first two input, as readline reads after a linebreak was entered

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy I don't know what a better method, all I want is for it to read all the lines one after the other as soon as the input is pasted on the console without waiting for the enter command